__DEV__ not defined for React Native Jest in React + React Native monorepo
I have a monorepo with a React project and a React Native project, they both run fine but the jest tests do not work on React Native tests
I'm getting the error:
 FAIL  packages/app/components/index.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: __DEV__ is not defined

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/index.js:261:1)
      at Module._compile (node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:117:24)
      at Object.newLoader (node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:121:7)
      at ScriptTransformer.requireAndTranspileModule (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:798:66)

Tests pass on index.test.web.tsx
My jest.config.js has
  {
      preset: "react-native",
      transform: {
        "^.+\\.tsx$": "babel-jest",
      },

My babel.config.js is
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-react',
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
  ],
  plugins: [
      ["@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods", { "loose": true }],
      ["@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
      ["@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object", { "loose": true }], 
    ],
};

Full jest.config

  projects: [
    {
      preset: "jest-expo/web",
      transform: {
        "^.+\\.web.tsx?$": [
          "babel-jest",
        ],
      },
      moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
      testMatch: ["**/*.test.web.tsx", "**/*.test.web.ts"],
      testEnvironment: "jsdom",
      moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", '<rootDir>', '<rootDir>/mocks'],
      moduleNameMapper: {
        "\\.scss$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js",
}
      setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],

    },
    {
      preset: "react-native",
      globals: {
        __DEV__: true
      },
      transform: {
        "^.+\\.tsx$": "babel-jest",
      },
      transformIgnorePatterns: [
        "node_modules/(?!(react-native|@react-native|react-native-linear-gradient|react-native-reanimated)/)",
      ],
      moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
      testMatch: ["**/*.test.tsx"],
      testEnvironment: "react-native",
      moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", '<rootDir>'],
      },
      setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
    },
  ],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ["rootDir/dist/"],

};


I've tried adding the global variable to jest.config.js
    {
      preset: "react-native",
      globals: {
        __DEV__: true
      },


I've tried ts-jest
  {
      preset: "react-native",
      transform: {
        "^.+\\.tsx?$": [
          "ts-jest",
          {
            tsconfig: "tsconfig.jest.json",
          },
        ]
      },

I've tried using jest-react-native
I've tried using preset: 'jest-expo/ios' too
I've also added /* global __DEV__ */ to the top of index.test.tsx
